# missing export excel from crystal report

Tags: excel, vb6, crystal-reports, windows-7-x64

I have a vb6 application with crystal report 8. Running this application -

- on window xp: one pc has Excel option like the below picture but
  another pc doesn't have
- on window 7: no Excel option

[image: Export of Crystal Report 8]

I browsed /windows/crystal and found U2FRTF.DLL is extra. And then I put it under another xp pc but still not see the option. Am I missing some steps - register dll ?

[image: Dll in one window xp]

I'd like to have this excel option on window 7 64 bit. Please share your ideas.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 64 bit Windows system will open the 64 bit ODBC manager, but VB6 is 32 bit application. So you need to open the 32bit DSN manager to add your DSN. It can be found under: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the dll with XLS in the name , probably u2fxls.dll. Check if there are any other dlls with XLS on the machine where this is working.